# Adding text to start of each new line in a .txt file

Tags: file, text, cmd, file-manipulation

I would like to add a predefined text to each new line on a text file and create a new text file with the added text. Please help.

Comment: Under which OS ? Is the added text the same for all lines ? In this case, just do: "sed -e 's/^/yourtext/' old_file > new_file"

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, this will do it:

```
(for /f "delims=" %L in (oldfile.txt) do @echo predefined text %L)> newfile.txt
```

Note that in a batch file you'll need to use double `%` signs:

```
(for /f "delims=" %%L in (oldfile.txt) do @echo predefined text %%L)> newfile.txt
```

Note also that if you don't put the ">" right after the %L, you will get a space after every line. If you use ">>" instead of ">" you will keep adding on to newfile.txt instead of creating a new one each time you run it.

Comment: Note that %L works when you type this line in on the command line.  If you want to put it in a batch or cmd file, you need two percent signs on L.  So it'd be %%L instead of %L.

Comment: Edited slightly for correctness and noting other issues. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: *sigh* ok, I'll refrain from editing, then. In this form it's incorrect, you know? Just try it with a file that contains more than just a single line of text. Agreed though, that digits don't cause harm in this specific case.

Comment: Johannes was right...you need parens or the redirection applies to the echo instead of the for.