# How to Insert Before IP

Tags: linux, windows, bash

I have a single file contents with thousand of IP's, my problem is how can i add all the IP line with 'allow from' for example as below:

From This:

```
27.146.0.0/16
49.50.12.0/19
49.50.44.0/20
49.50.60.0/22
```

To Be this:

```
allow from 27.146.0.0/16
allow from 49.50.12.0/19
allow from 49.50.44.0/20
allow from 49.50.60.0/22
allow from 49.124.0.0/15
allow from 57.73.15.0/24
```

Is there any Windows tools can do that or Linux command should be ok too. Please help

Comment: on windows, you could open the file with any editor with replace feature (regex supported), for example, vim, emacs, notepad++, ultraedit, editplus, eclipse, (MS-Word?) and replace the beginning of the line with the fixed text.

Comment: The editors column/block mode (UltraEdit: Alt-C) is even better for the example above (no dialog/mouse). Select the column before the lines and just type "allow from ", done. Don't forget to exit column/block mode again.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with using a real manly editor?

In Vim/gVim:

1. <kbd>gg</kbd>: place the cursor in the start of the file
2. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>: start visual block mode
3. <kbd>G</kbd>: move the cursor to the end of the file, selecting every line
4. <kbd>I</kbd>: Enter Insert Mode
5. Type your string: <kbd>allow from</kbd>
6. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to leave Insert Mode.
7. <kbd>:wq</kbd> Save and exit.
8. Done!

Sed is probably easier...

Comment: I normally find that using vim macros/block mode is the way to go in these types of situations.  It gets the job done way faster then screwing around with a complex sed/awk command.

Comment: Virtual block mode is great unless you are working on a very large file / data set. Sed/awk are not complicated for things like this. "sed -i 's/^/allow from /' file"

Answer (score 1):

## Linux

With awk:

```
$ awk '$0="allow from "$0' file
allow from 27.146.0.0/16
allow from 49.50.12.0/19
allow from 49.50.44.0/20
allow from 49.50.60.0/22
```

As `$0` is the whole string, we append text in the beginning of it. Then, it gets printed because the default behaviour of `awk` is `{print $0}`.

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^/allow from /' file
allow from 27.146.0.0/16
allow from 49.50.12.0/19
allow from 49.50.44.0/20
allow from 49.50.60.0/22
```

As `^` means beginning of the line, we replace it with the "allow from " text. This way, the "new beginning of file" becomes the text you want to add.

Both examples will show you the output in your screen. To save it, do `command file > new_file`.

## Windows

This answer may help you: [Adding text to start of each new line in a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253134/adding-text-to-start-of-each-new-line-in-a-txt-file). However, as Kent pointed out in comments, any editor can make it. I strongly recommend Notepad++ for this kind of purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk`

```
awk '{print "allow from "$0}' <filename>
```